# Hyperbola with its directrix

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

The equation $9x^2 - 16y^2 -18x +32y-151=0$ represents a hyperbola . We have to find the equation of its directrix.

I simplified the equation and got :   $$(3x-1)^2 -(4y-1)^2 = 151$$

And found that its center is $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4})$ .

But I am not getting how to find the equation of the directrix . For a standard hyperbola it is $x = \frac{a}{e}$   where $e$ is the eccentricity.

Comment: Your simplified equation is not correct: check your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have rewritten your equation as
$$
{(x-x_0)^2\over a^2}-{(y-y_0)^2\over b^2}=1,
$$
then the equation of a directrix is $x=x_0+a/e$, where $e=\sqrt{1+b^2/a^2}$.